# Mysql where clauses

Tags: mysql

[image]

```
select * from staff
LEFT JOIN servicereservation
on servicereservation.snic = staff.snic
where servicereservation.starttime!='04:30:00 '
AND servicereservation.endtime!='05:00:00'
OR servicereservation.snic IS NULL ;
```

i need to find staff member name which are available on a specific time of a day. time is in servicereservation table & day is in reservation table. i dont know how to map these 3 tables. i tried this. but didnt connect with reservation. please let me a way to do this.

Comment: what type are `starttime`  and  `endtime` ?

Comment: You probably should include a sample data, looks like you need solve overlap times

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform the joins using the keys and performing the filtering on the dates from the appropriate table. Try this:

```
SELECT A.* FROM
STAFF A LEFT JOIN SERVICERESERVATION B ON (A.SNIC = B.SNIC) 
LEFT JOIN RESERVATION C ON (B.RID = C.RID) 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(C.RESERVATEIONDATE, '%d/%m/%Y')=
[Your reservation date in dd/MM/YYYY string format] 
AND DATE_FORMAT(B.STARTTIME,'%H:%i:%s')=
[your reservation start time in HH:mm:ss format] 
AND DATE_FORMAT(B.ENDTIME,'%H:%i:%s')=
[your reservation end time in HH:mm:ss format];
```

For more information on formating sql dates see; [MySQL DATE_FORMAT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp).
You should note that in this case the hour of the time here is in the 24 hour time format. So 1pm has an hour 13.

Answer (score 0):

Normal solution is to put the check to exclude rows from the LEFT OUTER JOINed table in the ON condition of the JOIN. The you can just check for NULL in the WHERE clause:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM staff
LEFT JOIN servicereservation
ON servicereservation.snic = staff.snic
AND servicereservation.starttime != '04:30:00'
AND servicereservation.endtime != '05:00:00'
WHERE servicereservation.snic IS NULL ;
```

Although I suspect you actually want to just use a check of a single time being between the start and end time.